# jquery validate plugin with dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

How to use this code (from the [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ajaxSubmit-intergration-demo.html)) if the form isn't created yet:

```
jQuery("#form").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
      target: "#result"
    });
  }
});
```

One way which doesn't work is to call the validation on a `on('click',` like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.submitBtn', function(){
   var $form =$('form'+this.id);
       $form.validate({
         submitHandler: function($form) {
           $form.ajaxSubmit({
             target: "#result"
           });
         }
       });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `jQuery("#form").validate().form()` after the form is created.
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.submitBtn', function(){
   var $form =$('#form'+this.id);
       $form.validate({
         submitHandler: function($form) {
           $($form).ajaxSubmit({  //need to properly refer to jQuery object
             target: "#result"
           });
         }
       }).form();
});
```

Comment: hmm, its saying, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'form' of undefined"

Comment: Ooh, looks like you are missing a `#` sign in the selector. `$('#form'+this.id)`

Comment: It works now! One change is that I needed to properly jQuery-ify the `blah.ajaxSubmit` function, i updated your answer to make it work, thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I just think `form()` is a pretty bad name for that function and isn't intuitive at all.

Comment: agree, this thing is driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer to a similar questions could help you out a lot https://stackoverflow.com/a/4359915/351366

Here's a shot at making it more specific to your code

Create a custom event to fire once your form is on the page

```
$(document).bind('bindForm', function (e) {
    jQuery("#form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
          jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
             target: "#result"
          });
        }
    });
});
```

Then when your form is loaded, trigger your custom event

```
$(document).trigger('bindForm'); //trigger our validate form
```

When you want to check to see if your form is valid in another function

```
$(".submitBtn").live("click",function() {
    if (!$("#form").validate().form()) {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the link and answer, Brian's suggestion seems a little more succinct so that's what i'll go with but good to know

Comment: No worries, I agree that is more of what you probably want, and I also learned something as well.