# Using jQuery Validation Plugin with dynamic form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a page that contains multiple forms, and each form can contain any number of elements that have a common root in its name. I'm trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952810/159710) to validate a form when it's submitted, but I get a `TypeError: a.data(...) is undefined` error on `jquery.validate.js`. My code is below.

```
    var valForm = function(kit_id) {
        $('input[name^="kit_desc_"]').each(function() {
            $(this).rules("add", {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Please enter a description"
                }
            });
        });

        $("#frm_" + kit_id).validate({
            errorElement: "div",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                $("#error_modal").html(error);
            }
        });

        if (! $("#frm_" + kit_id).valid()) {
            // a dialog box will appear listing the errors.
            $("#error_modal").dialog();
        }
    };
```

The function is called when a link is clicked.

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="valForm(1);" class="button136">Save</a>`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to call `.validate()` on the form before you can call `.rules()` on the inputs in that form. You should also call `.rules()` only on the inputs in the form you're submitting.

```
var valForm = function(kit_id) {
    var form = $("#frm_" + kit_id);
    form.validate({
        errorElement: "div",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $("#error_modal").html(error);
        }
    });

    form.find('input[name^="kit_desc_"]').each(function() {
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Please enter a description"
            }
        });
    });

    if (! form.valid()) {
        // a dialog box will appear listing the errors.
        $("#error_modal").dialog();
    }
};
```

Comment: *"I think you have to call `.validate()` on the form before you can call `.rules()`"* ~ [that is absolutely correct](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).